# Mac doesn't think my Microsoft Bluetooth mouse is a mouse so I can't change the sensitivity

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, mouse

I have a MacBook Air M1 and [this Microsoft Bluetooth mouse](https://www.officeworks.com.au/shop/officeworks/p/microsoft-bluetooth-mouse-black-msbtmsebk) and I don't think my Mac recognises the Bluetooth mouse as being a mouse. I remember when I first connected it the keyboard setup assistant came up.

If I go to System Preferences > Mouse > Set Up Bluetooth Mouse then the mouse never comes up. However I can connect the mouse by just going to Bluetooth.

The problem is that the mouse is very sensitive and the tracking speed control in the mouse section of System Preferences does nothing to this mouse. But if I play a video game that has its own sensitivity setting in the game then that does work.

Interestingly, the primary mouse button setting in System Preferences does work.

Can someone help me change my mouse sensitivity? Perhaps connect it properly as a mouse? Thank you so much for your help.

EDIT:

I will add that I had an old mouse with this same computer that did work effectively. But I don't have that anymore.

Comment: Did you read the Q&A on Officeworks? There are 7 questions re Macs and iPads: 1 says works, 1 says yes but reduced functionality, and 5 say not compatible. If it was sold to you as Mac compatible, take it back for a refund.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by using the [USB Overdrive](https://www.usboverdrive.com) app. I can change the sensitivity in there.